# Bower doesn't add dependency to index.html

Tags: angularjs, bower, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I'm trying to add the angular-flot library to a yeoman scaffolded angular project.

I added it using

```
bower i --save angular-flot
```

which pulled it into my bower_components directory but didn't add it to the index.html file.

I added it manually (as well as a reference to the flot CDN) and it works fine using

```
grunt serve
```

however, when I do

```
grunt build
```

and load the index.html file from the `/dist` directory, I get an error that the angular-flot is not included. So I think it's not making it through minification.

This is how the relevant section of my index.html look. I manually added the three lines between `endbower` and `endbuild`

```
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.2/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-flot/angular-flot.js"></script>

<!-- endbuild -->
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried running `grunt wiredep`? This should add the dependency to index.html.
Also, you need to make sure your dependency is included in `app.js`:

```
angular.module('yourApp', [
  'ngMessages',
  'ngRoute',
  'ngSanitize',
  //...
  'angular-flot'
])
```

Comment: I am including the dependency, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: `grunt wiredep` doesn't add it and it completes without error. It does add the other dependencies. I'll update my question to include the relevant section of index.html

Comment: Maybe grunt becomes confused during the "cdnify" step during grunt build. Could be because of the manual CDN entry you added, but just guessing. Maybe remove all manually added stuff and re-wiredep/grunt build it?

Comment: Removing the manual stuff and re-running `grunt wiredep` did add the angular-flot dependency. However, I still need to manually add the CDN reference for the Flot library (it is not included with angular-flot). The `grunt build` step strips out the manual CDN reference.